# Indexed access out of bounds: 1, 0 : Solr elevate issue with distributed search

Tags: java, solr, bigdata, solrj, sharding

### I have an issue regarding solr elevation query component and distributed searching(sharding).

Almost 2 days I have been doing investigations regarding elevation query and distributed search in big data.

> In solr I have 1 core (name ="all") for sharding with no data, and multiple cores which contain various data. After lots of investigations I found that my main core (all) has to contain other cores data ids for making elevation in "select" request handler(I have added 
>   "
>         elevator
>       " code in select request handler). For now I am able to elevate documents in shards, but when I add some document in elevate.xml which query will execute lots of documents (2000+) **solr returns "Indexed access out of bounds: 1, 0"**. But when query execute less count of documents it works correctly.

### The full error is:

```
{
    "responseHeader":{
        "status":500,
        "QTime":43
    },
    "error":{
        "msg":"Indexed access out of bounds: 1, 0",
        "trace":"java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Indexed access out of bounds: 1, 0\n\tat java.util.Objects.outOfBounds(java.base@9-internal/Objects.java:365)\n\tat java.util.Objects.checkIndex(java.base@9-internal/Objects.java:436)\n\tat java.util.Objects.checkIndex(java.base@9-internal/Objects.java:388)\n\tat java.util.ArrayList.get(java.base@9-internal/ArrayList.java:435)\n\tat org.apache.solr.common.util.NamedList.getVal(NamedList.java:182)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.component.ShardFieldSortedHitQueue$ShardComparator.sortVal(ShardFieldSortedHitQueue.java:146)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.component.ShardFieldSortedHitQueue$1.compare(ShardFieldSortedHitQueue.java:161)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.component.ShardFieldSortedHitQueue$1.compare(ShardFieldSortedHitQueue.java:153)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.component.ShardFieldSortedHitQueue.lessThan(ShardFieldSortedHitQueue.java:91)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.component.ShardFieldSortedHitQueue.lessThan(ShardFieldSortedHitQueue.java:33)\n\tat org.apache.lucene.util.PriorityQueue.upHeap(PriorityQueue.java:263)\n\tat org.apache.lucene.util.PriorityQueue.add(PriorityQueue.java:140)\n\tat org.apache.lucene.util.PriorityQueue.insertWithOverflow(PriorityQueue.java:156)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.mergeIds(QueryComponent.java:924)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.handleRegularResponses(QueryComponent.java:585)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.handleResponses(QueryComponent.java:564)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:423)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:177)\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2503)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:710)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:516)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:382)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:326)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1751)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:283)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:108)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@9-internal/Thread.java:804)\n",
        "code":500
    }
}
```

### The Java stack trace in the JSON is:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Indexed access out of bounds: 1, 0
    at java.util.Objects.outOfBounds(java.base@9-internal/Objects.java:365)
    at java.util.Objects.checkIndex(java.base@9-internal/Objects.java:436)
    at java.util.Objects.checkIndex(java.base@9-internal/Objects.java:388)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(java.base@9-internal/ArrayList.java:435)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.NamedList.getVal(NamedList.java:182)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.ShardFieldSortedHitQueue$ShardComparator.sortVal(ShardFieldSortedHitQueue.java:146)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.ShardFieldSortedHitQueue$1.compare(ShardFieldSortedHitQueue.java:161)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.ShardFieldSortedHitQueue$1.compare(ShardFieldSortedHitQueue.java:153)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.ShardFieldSortedHitQueue.lessThan(ShardFieldSortedHitQueue.java:91)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.ShardFieldSortedHitQueue.lessThan(ShardFieldSortedHitQueue.java:33)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.PriorityQueue.upHeap(PriorityQueue.java:263)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.PriorityQueue.add(PriorityQueue.java:140)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.PriorityQueue.insertWithOverflow(PriorityQueue.java:156)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.mergeIds(QueryComponent.java:924)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.handleRegularResponses(QueryComponent.java:585)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.handleResponses(QueryComponent.java:564)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:423)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:177)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2503)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:710)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:516)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:382)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1751)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@9-internal/Thread.java:804)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Solr?

Comment: Solr version is 7_2